# The image of a function defined as a regular polygon with $n$ > 0 sides inside a circumference of radius 1 and center 0.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, area

The following problem has been passed to me trough a friend studying for a local math olympics, but I can't get my head around it:

Consider C a circle with center (0,0) and radius 1, that is:
$$ C = \{(x,y):x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\} $$
Given any natural number $n$ > 0 show that a function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow C$ exists such that:

1. The set image of $f$, denoted by $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is a regular polygon with a minimum of $n$ sides and
2. $|\operatorname{Area}(\operatorname{Im}(f))-\pi| < \dfrac{1}{n}$.

The exercise doesn't seems to be complex, but I'm quite baffled by it. Any tips on how to start it or some key concepts that I've missed that would help in its solution would be greatly appreciated. As an additional input, my main problem with the exercise is the idea of a function that can be defined as a regular polygon, since I can't quite understand how one could do that.

Comment: I think of a polygon as just consisting of a set of line segments, so my first reaction to the problem was that it's trivial.  Perhaps you're right, though; they may be referring to the region of the plane enclosed by those segments.  Then you need to read about [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)

Comment: Does $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ suppose to fill the area or only to be the area boundary? In the former case it's more convinient to build the inverse $f^{-1}$ and show it's one-to-one. (like if for it was a filled disc required, I'd consider $0< r\le 1,\,0\le\theta< 2\pi$, then squeeze $\theta$ to $[0,1)$, then mix (interleave) the digits or $r$ and $\theta'$)

Comment: @saulspatz It is not demanded that $f$ be continuous.

Comment: @WhatsUp True, but does that help?  Is there an easier way to fill a two-dimensional region if the function isn't required to be continuous?

Comment: @saulspatz I mean... it suffices to note that they both have continuum cardinality...

Comment: @WhatsUp Oh, of course your'e right.  For some reason, I was thinking about explicitly constructing the function, but the problem doesn't require that.

Comment: Hint: check the demonstration of $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} sen(x)/x = 1$